# azure storage VM data disk add

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-storage, azure-virtual-machine

If you deploy a new VM in Azure. You add a data disk to the VM. Later, you notice that the data disk is assigned “E” for the drive letter. You need to ensure that the data disk is assigned “D” as the drive letter. What should you do first?

1. Remap the pagefile.sys drive to "F".
2. Remap the system drive to "F".
3. Convert the data disk to premium storage.
4. Convert the VM to use the Resource Manager model.
5. Convert the data disk to a managed disk.

Comment: Is it an exam question?;-)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to convert it to the managed disk. Then it will allow you to make changes in it.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to attach the disk as a managed disk, then temporarily move pagefile.sys to C drive, change the drive letter, then move back the pagefile.sys to the D drive. More details can be found **[here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/change-drive-letter)**